# ı got 'TypeError: Data location must be "storage" or "memory" for parameter in function, but none was given.'

Tags: truffle

I am trying to do truffle migrate but i got this error

```
$ truffle migrate

Compiling .\contracts\Election.sol...
Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol...

Compilation warnings encountered:

/C/Users/asus/election/contracts/Election.sol:24:5: Warning: This declaration shadows an existing declaration.
function Election () public {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

/C/Users/asus/election/contracts/Election.sol:3:1: The shadowed declaration is here:
contract Election {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

/C/Users/asus/election/contracts/Election.sol:1:1: SyntaxError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity 0.4.24;
^---------------------^

/C/Users/asus/election/contracts/Election.sol:24:5: SyntaxError: 
Functions are not allowed to have the same name as the contract. If you intend this to be a constructor, use "constructor(...) { ... }" to define it.
function Election () public {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

/C/Users/asus/election/contracts/Migrations.sol:1:1: SyntaxError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
^----------------------^

,/C/Users/asus/election/contracts/Election.sol:24:5: Warning: This declaration shadows an existing declaration.
function Election () public {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

/C/Users/asus/election/contracts/Election.sol:3:1: The shadowed declaration is here:
contract Election {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

/C/Users/asus/election/contracts/Election.sol:29:28: TypeError: Data location must be "storage" or "memory" for parameter in function, but none was given.
function addCandidate (string _name) private {
                       ^----------^
Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.0.1 (core: 5.0.1)
Node v11.6.0
```

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: You should share your source code in order to get the best help. A lot of the errors seem pretty straightforward, and I think all of them are because you updated to Truffle v5 (solidity 0.5.0). This comes with some breaking changes, so you should edit your contract accordingly (See [Solidity 0.5.0 breaking changes](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I am understanding, try to use a more recent solidity compiler writing as statement `pragma solidity ^0.5.0;` since you are using truffle v 0.5.

With Solidity 0.5 you must declare a constructor with `constructor` keyword (as one of your errors states).

For your last listed error now you need to specify whether your arrays parameters are `memory` or `storage`. Try to change the signature of `addCandidate (string _name)` to `addCandidate (string memory _name)`.

For more information like these check the changelog for solidity v 0.5 here: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: Data location must be "storage" or "memory" for parameter in the function, but none was given.
function addCandidate(string _name) private{
```

For this type of error try to change the array parameters whether they belong to Storage or memory.
add memory to your function local variable.

```
function addCandidate(string memory _name)
```

Answer (score -1):

function addCandidate(string memory _name)

This works so go for it and vo solidity version
Unistall the old version and go for the new version.

$npm install sol@version